# How to install oracle_fdw extension in postgresql 9.4

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, postgresql-9.4

I'm trying to installing oracle_fdw packages in postgres 9.4. But it is throwing the exception below.

Error:

```
/home/ramesh/Downloads/oracle_fdw-1.2.0# make
make: pg_config: Command not found
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.